# How do I trick a webpage to think its tab is visible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer, grafana, google-chrome-headless

Having lots of tabs running various webpages where I use Puppeteer to refresh each tab and then take a screenshot. Since this is automatic most tabs are not the topmost tab (visible) when doing the refresh and taking the screenshot. This works on most pages, but some have a feature where if they are not visible they will not refresh the page until they are, resulting in blank screenshots. Grafana is currently the only one I have issues with.

How can I trick a webpage to think it's visible even though it's in the background and not actually visible?